# Using 2 external screens with my laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, mini-displayport, display-adapter

I have a ASUS Zenbook Pro laptop, and a Dell S2715H 27" monitor connected to it using HDMI. The laptop has 2 ports for display: 1xhdmi and 1xmini displayport. The monitor only has 2xhdmi.

If I buy another Dell S2715H monitor, Will I be able to use both screens (extending each other) if I connect it to the laptop with an hdmi cable connected to a hdmi-to-mini displayport adapter that's connected to the mini displayport on my latop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line is a little confusing, but if this is what you're trying to describe:

```
 --------                                                   ---------
|        |-HDMI port---------------(HDMI cable)------------|monitor 1|
| laptop |                                                  =========
|        |-MiniDP---(MiniDP/HDMI adapter)---(HDMI cable)---|monitor 2|
 --------                                                   ---------
```

Then, yes, that should work.

[This guy tried doing the same thing](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-zenbook-pro-ux501-owners-lounge.772953/page-102#post-10196546) (but with different monitors) and he got it to work.  I can't be sure, however, that he's using the same model Zenbook Pro that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your laptop is a UX501VW, if you buy a decent quality adaptor ([this](http://gizmodo.com/5380669/mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter-with-digital-audio-review) is one of the first google results) you should be fine. Your CPU's integrated graphics are stated on intel's site to be able to run 3 outputs and should be capable enough for the 1080p monitors + your laptop screen. I have seen someone suggesting on a forum that it may use some more RAM (since HD Graphics use RAM for video memory) so you might want to watch out for that, but it will most likely not be a problem.
Just don't expect to be able to play any games from the current decade on this setup. The GTX 960M isn't up for that.

Comment: Of course I am not an expert on this, so maybe it's better to wait for a few more oppinions.

Comment: Why should it cost 70$? What's the difference from the 7$ ones?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know. I just searched for a cheaper one (8$) and the reviews were all positive so I guess they are fine. I didn't expect there to be such big price differences. Quite weird.